# How to change the asp.net gridview column width using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am creating a webpage using Asp.Net, C#, bootstrap and jquery. Now, I have taken a grdiview and given the bootstrap "table" class as the css-class for the gridview.
Now, data will be loaded into the gridview using jquery ajax. The detail code is given below:

**.aspx page**

```
<div id="user_list">
   <asp:GridView ID="grdUsersList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover" HeaderStyle-CssClass="info"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**jquery ajax**

```
function showActiveUsers(stat) {
alert(stat);
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:49541/Admin_UserDet.svc/AllUsers?stat="+stat,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
    success: populateUsersList,
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        alert("Error: " + errorType);
        alert(exception);
    }
});
}

function populateUsersList(response) {
//console.log(response);

$('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').empty();

if (response.length > 0) {
    $('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<tr><th class="info" style="width: 100px;">Name</th>\
                            <th class="info">Login Id</th>\
                            <th class="info">Email Id</th>\
                            <th class="info">Phone No.</th>\
                            <th class="info">Designation</th>\
                            <th class="info">Reporting To</th>\
                            <th class="info">Business</th>\
                            <th class="info">User type</th></tr>');
    $.each(response, function (index, itemData) {
        $('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<tr><td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserName + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.LoginId + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.EmailId + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Phone + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Designation + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.ReportingTo + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.BusinessAssigned + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserType + '</td></tr>');
    });
}
}
```

As you can see that I have used the "Style=Width:100px;" for just 1st column. But, still the width is not getting changed.

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: add new css class name "thWidth" in th tag. and define 
.thWidth{ width:100px !important;}

Answer (score 0):

After Ajax call,ie after grid is rendered apply the width,ie

```
$.ajax({
 //your AJAX operations
});

//Then apply width
$('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').find('th').css('width', '100')
```